# Spring Boot. Dynamic creation of another bean after of initialization of the first one

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I write a spring boot starter, which provides custom annotation. Expecting that any bean `X` that is marked with this annotation `A` will be intercepted and based on it (it will be injected as a dependency) another bean `Y` will be created. This new bean `Y` is a technical bean, and it is expected that the library consumer will not intentionally inject it into their beans. But it is important to me that it be initialized in the context.

I wrote such a bean post processor. This is not real code, but close to it.

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    private final ApplicationContext context;
    private Map<String, ParamsContainer> candidates = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (isCandidate(bean)) {
            candidates.putIfAbsent(beanName, collectParams(bean));
        }
        return BeanPostProcessor.super.postProcessBeforeInitialization(bean, beanName);
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (candidates.containsKey(beanName)) {
            var registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
            BeanDefinition beanDefinition = makeBeanDefinition(bean, candidates.get(beanName));
            var newBeanName = format("%s_binding", beanName);
            registry.registerBeanDefinition(newBeanName, beanDefinition);

            //Hack to initialize new bean just now
            context.getBean(newBeanName);
        }
        return BeanPostProcessor.super.postProcessAfterInitialization(bean, beanName);
    }
}
```

In the `*Before*` method, I check all objects for the presence of my annotation (`isCandidate` method) and read metadata from it (`collectParams` method). Then, in `*After*` method, I determine by the bean name whether it is necessary to determine the technical bean (`Y`) by the presence of the original bean in the map.

This code works as expected, but I have 2 questions:

1. I don't like that I have to explicitly call `context.getBean(newBeanName);` to initialize a new bean, it looks like a crutch. How can I tell Spring (when registering or creating a `beanDefinition`, for example) that the bean should be initialized immediately, without waiting for a request? (`beanDefinition` create with `lazy` flag is false)
2. Is such an implementation through BPP the best solution, or is there another? (Provided that in the new bean I need an instance of the original one)

Comment: Why can't you make use `@Conditional` or `@DependsOn`?

Comment: In this case, the consumer of the library will need to initialize the internal beans of my starter in their configuration. This is contrary to the philosophy of spring-boot-starters (when we can activate a configuration by simply writing a dependency).
I can't declaratively declare these technical beans in the starter, simply because I don't know the number of `X` beans, nor their type, nor their name. I can get this information only after the fact in runtime.

Comment: `BeanPostProcessor` is the contract for post-processing individual beans. It should not be used to register additional beans. You should use `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` or `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` to register beans. This will require you to change you detection of annotation `A` as you will have to examine bean definitions rather than bean instances.

Comment: In this case, I will have to pass the name of the `X` bean to the `BeanFactory` of the `Y` bean and than get there the `X` bean from the context in order to inject it. Is this definitely better than the current solution? 

I absolutely understand so BPP is for working with specific beans and is not the best place to define new ones. But it's also the only place I think I can get bean `X` ready and use it to define bean `Y`.